# How can I use the Richtext component (Wysiwyg) in my strapi plugin?

Tags: reactjs, plugins, strapi

I’m building a plugin that will allow users to upload a 3D asset and manage some content about that object in a JSON field. I’d also like to use the Richtext field along with the WYSIWYG component that comes with strapi.

I’m looking for a way to import and configure that component in the React component that I’m building in my plugin.

Is this possible, and if so, are there examples of how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the complete Richtext field built into Strapi: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/main/packages/core/admin/admin/src/content-manager/components/Wysiwyg

I don't think it's available with Strapi's published package, and you cannot find it with their [design system](https://design-system-git-main-strapijs.vercel.app/).

So I'd recommend looking into an alternative solution like using another WYSIWYG editor package instead.